# ошибка с валидацией

Tags: javascript, jquery

помогите исправить ошибку с валидацией. задача такая:

есть чек боксы и поле ввода. если какой либо из чек боксов помечен, а в поле ввод ничего не вписано, должна сработать валидация запрещающая отправить форму и `div.demo` обвестись красной рамкой. это работает, но если помечаю и ввожу текст, то при отправки он все равно помечается рамкой. в яваскрипте не силен. не могу разобраться что не правильно делаю.

```
$('.checker').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#altField').prop('required', true);

        if ($("#altField").val().length === 0) {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $(".demo").addClass("redb");
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('#altField').prop('required', false);
        $("button").click(function() {
            $(".demo").removeClass("redb");
        });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d82knaz4/

Comment: А не могли бы вы добавить шаги для воспроизведения. Я попробовал несколько вариантов, всё отработало нормально.

Comment: пометить любой чек бокс, вписать что либо в поле ввода и нажать кнопку отправки. :) она отправляет как и должна, но на момент пока грузится все равно красная рамка выскакивает :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо немного поменять обработчик сделать его таким:

```
$('.checker').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#altField').prop('required', true);
        $("button").click(function(){
            if( $("#altField").val().length === 0 ) {
                $(".demo").addClass("redb");
            } else {
                $(".demo").removeClass("redb");
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        $('#altField').prop('required', false);
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(".demo").removeClass("redb");
        }); 
    }
});
```

В отличие от вашего варианта, тут есть условие на удаление класса, когда поле не пустое. Так же тут эвент на клик назначается всегда, а не только когда поле пустое. Т.е. это фиксит проблему, когда что-то ввести в поле, потом отметить галочку и удалить из поля всё. Поле будет обязательным, но не будет красной рамки.

Comment: спасибо большое, все отлично теперь работает :)